# What are the advantages to choosing a 2nd Edition Monks over other classes?

Tags: monk, adnd-2e

It seems monks have the following:

- Unarmed dmg is 25% lethal, 75% non lethal
- The dmg is pre-calculated depending on what you roll on the chart of punching or wrestling or martial arts chart, you don't roll for dmg
- The ability score requirements for a monk are Wis 15, Int 14, Con 13, which means that your Strength and Dex will generally be bad, you will not get decent to hit modifiers nor will you get much extra dmg
- The high mastery and grand mastery specializations are not defined anywhere I can tell
- The armor bonus you get is conditional to the attacker being right in front of you, or else you are a sitting duck for slaughter
- You can't wear armor

**What am I missing?**

*I read the Complete Priests Handbook, the Complete Fighthers Handbook, the Players Handbook, the Players Options Spells and Magic and the Players Options Combat and Tactics ... All relevant material to understand the two different Monk kits, Unarmed combat and the relevant Specialization proficiencies.*

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is more of a rant that a question.  See our help center - "your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”" is specifically cited as a bad kind of question. What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 13):

Lots of classes in older D&D were not balanced to each other, and not balanced at every level of play.

One of the main advantages that 2E monks had with the wacky unarmed combat tables was decent odds of getting knockouts or stuns - they had better chance of bumping up and down the results on the table, giving you some advantage there or of pinning/restraining some enemies with wrestling. (of course, that requires a creature that can be knocked out or stunned, or a creature you can actually touch as opposed to a ghost or a pool of green slime...).

Being able to either stop the enemy from acting at all, or skipping the hitpoint buffer with a knockout became more valuable at higher levels, but of course, you're basically a glass cannon gambling on random conditions.  Normally, you'd want to be buffed in every possible way from your mages and magic items you've found or created to improve your AC and so on.

That said, mostly the monk was depending on you having outrageous stats and being very lucky.

The thing to realize about stat requirements is that unlike later editions, the default for play was random roll, and many groups did not let you swap around scores - so it was complete luck of the draw as to which stats you got high vs. low.  So, instead of looking at it and saying "Oh, the monk would have a sucky Strength & Dexterity" it was really more "I need to have been lucky enough to roll GREAT Strength & Dexterity AND made these required scores ON TOP of that."

Now, the reason this even works this way is that way back, players were randomly rolling up an entire war party of several characters.  The stat requirements basically meant most of your band would be Fighting Men, and everyone else who did something specialized or cool had more or higher requirements and therefore you had less of them.  Monks, way back, were super powerful, and so the odds of rolling stats good enough to get one were very difficult.

Most of the time, you'd be short on the stats for a Monk, and you'd pick something else instead.

Comment: The first sentence is where it's at. ie: Wizards were weak at the early levels and incredibly powerful at later level. This wasn't balanced at all and that was ok for a lot of players like me and the people I played with. This had to do with the flavour and character of the game rather than some sort of sterile, artificial feeling, numerical game balance.

Answer (score 0):

Read everything again. You're missing a lot of info.

Every martial art style has a base damage. I have 2 monks and one does a d8 and the other a d10 for damage—all 2nd edition rules. You may be missing info—try the Ninja Handbook or the Oriental Adventures book. Every martial art style I've seen has a base damage; those two have great abilities added to them as well. And don't use the punching, wresting, martial arts table from the Player's Handbook or DMG—that's when they suck. Trust me, I'm a proud player of a fighting monk kit with a −8 AC (despite not being able to wear armor), 1d10+26 damage with a fist, and 3 attacks a round.

Just remember that you need the Oriental Adventures or Ninja Handbook.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. I'd suggest that calling everyone else stupid in your very first post is probably not a positive way to get your point across.

Comment: Adding some more punctuation would also make your post more readable.

Comment: I removed the rant—that sort of thing would make at least a bit of sense on a forum, but we're not a forum and answers aren't threaded. I also did a first quick pass breaking this into sentences and fixing a few spelling issues.

Comment: @jerrittproctor, please see our site code of conduct at http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice. Take its guidance into account with your next post if you would. Thanks.